# How to get offset of canvas in CustomPainter's paint function?

Tags: flutter

lets say that we have a background image:

[image]

I want to render few views with shared background:

[image]

I think that I can use CustomPainter and draw my background image translated by canvas offset, but I don't know how to get that property inside paint function:

```
class PanelBackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var rect = Offset.zero & size;
    canvas.clipRect(rect);

    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(-canvasOffsetX, -canvasOffsetY), new Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

How can I calculate canvasOffsetX and canvasOffsetY?

I am using rows and columns to lay out my panels:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new Container(
              color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 128, 128),
            ),
            flex: 100,
          ),
          new Container(height: 10.0),
          new Container(
            color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 128, 128),
            height: 120.0,
          ),
          new Container(height: 10.0),
          new Expanded(
            child: new Container(
              child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                      color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 128, 128),
                    ),
                    flex: 50,
                  ),
                  new Container(width: 10.0),
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Container(
                      color: new Color.fromARGB(255, 128, 128, 128),
                    ),
                    flex: 50,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flex: 200,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you lay out all of the children - do you use rows + columns or are you specifying their positions manually? If you're able to add the code that would definitely make it quicker to test out.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie Good point, I've updated my question with example layout code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I don't know that it is necessarily a great idea, it is possible. The best explanation is probably just to look at this code:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SharedBackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;
  final RenderBox renderBox;
  final RenderBox parentRender;

  SharedBackgroundPainter({@required this.image, @required this.renderBox, @required this.parentRender});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var rect = ui.Offset.zero & size;

    var globalThisTopLeft = renderBox.localToGlobal(new ui.Offset(0.0, 0.0), ancestor: parentRender);

    canvas.clipRect(rect);
    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(-globalThisTopLeft.dx, -globalThisTopLeft.dy), new Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class BackgroundBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size size;
  final ui.Image image;
  final RenderBox parentRender;

  const BackgroundBuilder({Key key, @required this.size, @required this.image, @required this.parentRender})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
      assert(box != null);

      return new CustomPaint(
        size: new Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight),
        painter: new SharedBackgroundPainter(image: image, renderBox: box, parentRender: parentRender),
      );
    });
  }
}

class SharedBackgroundBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final ui.Image toDraw;
  final Size size;
  final RenderBox parentRender;

  const SharedBackgroundBuilder({Key key, @required this.toDraw, @required this.size, @required this.parentRender})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: new BackgroundBuilder(
            image: toDraw,
            size: size,
            parentRender: parentRender,
          ),
          flex: 100,
        ),
        new SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        new SizedBox(
          height: 120.0,
          child: new BackgroundBuilder(
            image: toDraw,
            size: size,
            parentRender: parentRender,
          ),
        ),
        new SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        new Expanded(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new BackgroundBuilder(
                    image: toDraw,
                    size: size,
                    parentRender: parentRender,
                  ),
                  flex: 50,
                ),
                new Container(width: 10.0),
                new Expanded(
                  child: new BackgroundBuilder(
                    image: toDraw,
                    size: size,
                    parentRender: parentRender,
                  ),
                  flex: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          flex: 200,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// This is to resize an image to the size of the overall structure. Note that this will
/// only work in an environment where LayoutBuilder can find constraints.

class ImageResizingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;
  final BoxFit boxfit;

  ImageResizingPainter(this.image, this.boxfit);

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    final ui.Rect rect = ui.Offset.zero & size;
    final Size imageSize = new Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

    FittedSizes sizes = applyBoxFit(boxfit, imageSize, size);

    // if you don't want it centered for some reason change this.
    final Rect inputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
    final Rect outputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, rect);
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, new Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class ImageResizer extends StatelessWidget {
  final ui.Image image;
  final BoxFit boxFit;

  // if you want a different boxfit you can set it. See BoxFit documentation.
  const ImageResizer({Key key, @required this.image, this.boxFit = BoxFit.cover}) : super(key: key);

  ui.Image getResizedImage(Size size) {
    var pictureRecorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    CustomPainter painter = new ImageResizingPainter(image, boxFit);
    painter.paint(canvas, size);
    return pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size.width.floor(), size.height.floor());
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
      var size = new Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
      // This might not be a good idea to do in the build function, but we're going to ignore that
      // and do it anyways.
      ui.Image resizedImage = getResizedImage(size);
      return new SharedBackgroundBuilder(toDraw: resizedImage, size: size, parentRender: box);
    });
  }
}

class ImageDrawer extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

  ImageDrawer(this.image);

  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    canvas.drawImage(image, ui.Offset.zero, new Paint());
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

/// This is just to build an image to display. I'm too lazy to load one =D

class GradientPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, ui.Size size) {
    Rect rect = ui.Offset.zero & size;
    var linearGradient = new LinearGradient(
      colors: [Colors.red, Colors.green],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    );

    var shader = linearGradient.createShader(rect);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, new Paint()..shader = shader);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class GradientGetter extends StatelessWidget {
  // I'm too lazy to create an image so I'm just drawing a gradient
  ui.Image getGradientImage(Size size) {
    var pictureRecorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    GradientPainter painter = new GradientPainter();
    painter.paint(canvas, size);
    return pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size.width.floor(), size.height.floor());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      var size = new Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
      // remove the / 20 to get it smooth again, it's just there to test
      // out the scaling.
      var changedSize = size / 20.0;
      ui.Image gradientImage = getGradientImage(changedSize);
      assert(gradientImage != null);
      return new ImageResizer(
        image: gradientImage,
      );
    });
  }
}

/// This is just so that you can copy/paste this and have it run.
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: new GradientGetter(),
        ));
  }
}
```

As I went through it I realized that it needs to be more complex than I originally thought - you have to deal with scaling the image to the size of the container etc. This does all that now, although I haven't tested it super extensively.

Also note that this gives no consideration to performance - it's almost for sure bad performance-wise.

Comment: Where should I call that code? I've tried in LayoutBuilder's builder callback and in my custom widget build function but it returned null in both cases.

Comment: Yeah actually that won't work all that well now I think about it - you have to call that after the layout pass. I'll update with a better answer when I get near a computer.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie That'd most likely lead to horrible performances. As you'd have to redraw after every frame.

Comment: @raver I've updated the answer with a much more thorough example (it does use the code I had posted originally). I've tested this and it works on my phone. You'll probably have to make some changes to get it to work with your image, but this should give you a good basis to work from.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie After further consideration I am not going to use CustomPainter at all (I am going to write a wrapper around Column and Row classes to pass offsets to children), but thanks for your effort, I've learnt a lot from your example, and accidentally you've fixed my other issue :).

Comment: What if we use drawPath instead of Rect ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and that it already has an answer, but I just had the same issue, and wanted to share my solution.

If we create a custom `RenderObject`, this can be solved quite easily:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// An image with a slight pattern.
///
/// The pattern is always the same on a certain part of the screen, even if the
/// widget itself doesn't cover the whole screen.
class Background extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  const Background({super.key});

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return BackgroundRenderObject(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, BackgroundRenderObject renderObject) {
    renderObject.screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  }
}

class BackgroundRenderObject extends RenderBox {
  BackgroundRenderObject(this._screenSize);

  Size _screenSize;

  set screenSize(Size value) {
    if (_screenSize == value) {
      return;
    }

    _screenSize = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    size = constraints.biggest;
  }
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;

    // The rect where the background should be painted.
    final drawRect = offset & size;

    // A rect covering the entire screen.
    // This ensures that the painted shader is the same no matter the offset
    // and size of the rect where the background is painted.
    final fullScreenRect = Offset.zero & _screenSize;


    const gradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Color(0xFF000824),
        Color(0xFF00283F),
        Color(0xFF001134),
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topRight,
      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    );

    final paint = Paint()..shader = gradient.createShader(fullScreenRect);

    canvas.drawRect(drawRect, paint);
  }
```